# std::regex not working as expected

Tags: c++, regex

I googled around but still cannot find the error.

Why does the following code print `false`, I expected `true`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string in("15\n");
    std::regex r("[1-9]+[0-9]*\\n",
                 std::regex_constants::extended);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::regex_match(in, r) << std::endl;
}
```

The option to use `regex_search` is not given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extra slash before the "\n" in your regex. The code prints `true` with just the slash removed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string in("15\n");
    std::regex r("[1-9]+[0-9]*\n",
                 std::regex_constants::extended);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::regex_match(in, r) << std::endl;
}
```

Edit: @rici explains why this is an issue in a comment:

> Posix-standard extended regular expressions (selected with `std::regex_constants::extended`) do not recognize C-escape sequences such as `\n`. See [Posix base definitions 9.4.2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_02): "The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by a  ( '\' ) is undefined."

Comment: What is your compiler and platform? It prints `true` for me with `gcc version 4.9.2 20141101 (Red Hat 4.9.2-1) (GCC)` when I use the command `g++ -std=c++11 r.cpp && ./a.out` to compile and run the program.

Comment: It's okay, I used the wrong `libc++` and thus obfuscated my regex. Thanks for help!

Comment: The regex engine see's string "\\n" as the escape sequence `\n`, meaning newline. With the string "\n" the engine see's a literal newline 0x0a character. Usually the string constructor won't translate that into a CRLF sequence. By all accounts, his regex should have worked, unless the match is picky and requires start/end anchors in `match`.

Comment: @sln: It works like a charm, had it first, but due to wrong setup I started to obfuscate the regex.

Comment: @NaCl - Shame on you !

Comment: @sln The version in the question threw a `regex_error` for me.

Comment: @sln: Posix-standard extended regular expressions (selected with `std::regex_constants::extended`) do not recognize C-escape sequences such as `\n`. See [Posix base definitions 9.4.2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_02): "The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by a <backslash> ( '\\' ) is undefined."

Comment: @rici: I think you should make a separate answer with that.

Comment: @nhahtdh: It's more an explanation of why the accepted answer is correct; if nwk doesn't edit the answer, I might do so later. The important thing is that *there is no such thing a universal regular expression syntax*; every tool has its own syntax, and you need to take that into account rather than assuming that the syntax you are familiar with is applicable in context.

Comment: @rici If you don't mind I'll edit the answer to include your explanation.